# HTTP code 500 on Django when I try to put a queryset on context

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.8

I'm trying to get a queryset on my IndexView on Django, when I try it, I have a HTTP code 500. 
I checked my template and it's path, and it's ok. 
Django: 3.0.5
Python 3.8.1

My views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import generic
    from .models import *
    from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
    from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
    from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
    from datetime import datetime

    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = "index.html"
        def get(self, request, **kwargs):
            domain = get_current_site(request)
            v = Visits(domain_name=domain, date=datetime.now())
            v.save()
        def get_queryset(self):
            return Domains.objects.all().only('domain').order_by('domain')
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['domains'] = Domains.objects.all().only('domain').order_by('domain')
            return context
```

When I remove the get_queryset,def_context function and put redenring return, it's works fine. Probably I'm doing something wrong on context and queryset jobs. But, I don't know what. 
    Somebody can help me.

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.8.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap_themes',
 'carroca',
 'core']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/acm/Documents/PyCharmProjects/91/python/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/acm/Documents/PyCharmProjects/91/python/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: The view carroca.views.IndexView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Thank you and Stay home!

Comment: Turn on Debug in your settings.py to tell us the exact error.